# Parasitic plant concept/other parasite

Tags: science-based, biology, creature-design

I believe there are precious few questions relating to the concept in general, but I was wondering if the concept of an organism absorbing large amounts of CO<sub>2</sub> from blood seemed reasonably plausible?  This question also could relate to the plausibility of nanorobots (which could be powered by CO<sub>2</sub> in theory).  What if such a parasitic creature was able to form some structure, like a mini organ that help it suck up CO<sub>2</sub>?

Comment: CO2 cannot generate energ because it cannot be further oxydized.

Comment: Besides @L.Dutch's comment, this sounds quite suspiciously like many fungi.

Comment: Aren't there methane producing bacteria that use CO2?  Also plants breathe CO2, right?

Comment: In order for the organism to be "parasitical", it would have to cause harm to the host. Simply taking CO2, a byproduct of human metabolism, does not make that organism a parasite.

Comment: C02 could easily be absorbed from blood in the veins using diffusion.

Comment: @Tom, in a very simplified version: plants use CO2 and solar energy to produce sugar. Then the sugar is used as energy source. Methane producing bacteria use organic matter as input, not CO2.

Comment: @Tom - How crucial are the 'parasitic' aspect and the 'CO2 for energy' concept to your question? As some have correctly pointed out, this is a bit of a misconception. If you are more interested in exploring the idea of a *symbiont* extracting CO2 from a human (for some purpose, not necessarily for energy generation), maybe change this question to reflect this?

Comment: this could be parasitic if the organism takes up CO2 to the point of suppressing the hypercarbic drive in humans.  This would mimic the symptoms of late stage emphysema.  There are two things that drive breathing in humans.  First is the hypercarbic drive which seeks to increase the ph in blood by getting rid of CO2.  The second, weaker drive is the hypoxic drive.

Answer (score 4):

Strictly speaking such an organism would be a symbiont and not a parasite.

Unfortunately CO<sub>2</sub> is quite low in energy so using it for "fuel" (either by an organism or by nanorobots) is problematic.

Plants actually use CO<sub>2</sub>, but they need to *add* energy to it in order to produce sugar+oxygen (plants actually breathe Oxygen and produce CO<sub>2</sub>, but photosynthesis is predominant, at least in daytime).

If You want to speculate about such a symbiote then You can think about something residing on (or in) the skin and using light to produce Oxygen from Carbon Dioxide and, perhaps also shielding from harmful radiation (ultraviolet and up).

Answer (score 1):

**Here are the variables:**

**CO<sub>2</sub> is not an energy source**:
As ZeoByte mentioned CO<sub>2</sub> cannot be used for energy, this is why plants need sunlight. They convert the easily found CO<sub>2</sub> into sugar which is an energy source they burn at night or when they need to.

**Parasite or Symbiote?**:
Parasites harm their hosts usually by taking something they need without giving anything of equivalence in return or cause collateral damage to their host. Symbiotes form a mutually beneficial relationship with their host. Example: a clown fish living in a anemone. The clown fish gets protection while the anemone gets bait to lure in potential food, that's a symbiotic relationship.

**With that out of the way we can focus on the mechanics:**

**Could a symbiote invade the human body and extract CO<sub>2</sub> from the blood? yes;**

**The immune system:**
The biggest challenge in this is the immune system which would react to kill any foreign organism or end up killing the host in overreaction (ie a fever > 108 degrees). Though, there are plenty of parasytic adaptations evolved to prevent this from happening.

**The organism:**
Needs a way to control its growth, if it grows in the wrong place it could impede important biological functions [constricting the heart, causing strokes or heart attacks etc.].

**The Energy:**
The organism would need to get energy in order to convert the CO<sub>2</sub>. It could get this from sunlight on the skin or it could get a fair amount from body heat. **Note:** it wouldn't necessarily turn skin green, not all photosynthetic organisms are green.

**Could it form its own organ in the host?** : yes and no, It would need evolutional help from the host to truly develop an efficient symbiotic organelle. Fortunately, our own intestines are a prime example of this very concept. Could it create one? sort of, it could evolutionarily know where to burrow in the body so as to not spread or grow into vital spots. There are parasites that avoid aggressive intrusion however there are plenty that love to explore.

**Finally Nanorobots:**
No, this is madness. Just as plants can't be powered by CO<sub>2</sub>  nor could nanorobots. Nanorobots could be solar powered like plants but will never be CO<sub>2</sub> powered. Nanorobots could extract the "C"arbon from CO<sub>2</sub> to make strong carbon structures but that would be the extent of their efficient O<sub>2</sub> production.

And no there arent few questions on this subject. Plenty of scientists are exploring this and hundreds of other angles on this. It wouldn't surprise me if in 20-100 years we have biological or synthetic nano-micro machine capable of building structures from air and sunlight. Well maybe 200.

Answer (score 0):

Consider **cancer**.

If your parasite is coming from the outside, there's a big fat chance that it will trigger immune system. Best chance that its cells come from **modifying existing somatic cell** (probably skin is the best, like ZioByte answer) into a mini-organ (a green swelling in the skin, with mutated chlorophyll).

Maybe in your world there is not enough sunlight to supply the energy needed for photosynthesis, so this plant evolved to live inside its host, taking the heat to perform photosynthesis.

The problem is, because heat is available 24/7, then it proceeds to absorb body heat until the host suffer from hypothermia, and finally die.

This is not really plausible, but may provide a way how this plant can be parasitic although it consumes CO<sub>2</sub> (which is beneficial).

Comment: hypothermia may be beneficial, depending on climate (think about rainforest, where normal cooling mechanisms are not really efficient). It is "fortunate" caption of CO2 happens together with release of O2, otherwise we could have heavy syncope problems. Our urge to breathe is *not* connected with lack of Oxygen, but with excess of CO2 in the blood stream; if something keeps removing CO2 (without adding O2) we could literally "forget" to breathe till we get syncope and die from hypoxia.